# Queryset: Return description by accessorys in the ordered (Django)

Tags: django, django-templates

Consider the next example:

```
class Vehicle(models.Model):
    vehicle = models.CharField(_('veículo'), max_length=50, unique=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(_(u'preço'), max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    kit_fabric = models.ForeignKey(
        "Kit", verbose_name=u'kit de fábrica', related_name='vehicle_kit')


class Accessory(models.Model):
    accessory = models.CharField(_(u'accessório'), max_length=50)
    price_accessory = models.DecimalField(
        _(u'preço'), max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)


class Kit(models.Model):
    kit = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class KitDetail(models.Model):
    kit = models.ForeignKey("Kit", verbose_name='kit', related_name='kit_det')
    accessory = models.ForeignKey(
        "Accessory", verbose_name=u'accessório', related_name='accessory_kit')
    quantity_accessory = models.PositiveIntegerField(_('quantidade'))

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.kit)


class Ordered(TimeStampedModel):
    customer = models.ForeignKey("Customer", verbose_name='cliente')
    employee = models.ForeignKey("Employee", verbose_name=u'funcionário')
    vehicle = models.ForeignKey("Vehicle", verbose_name=u'veículo')
    kit_optional = models.ForeignKey("Kit", verbose_name='kit opcional')
    dealership = models.ForeignKey(
        "Dealership", verbose_name=u'concessionária')
    kiosk = models.ForeignKey("Kiosk", verbose_name='quiosque')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=status_list, default='p')
```

How to return description by accessorys in the ordered?

That is, in my template i need :

```
{{ object.kit_optional.accessory }}
{{ object.kit_optional.price_accessory }}
{{ object.kit_optional.quantity_accessory }}
```

Otherwise, i try others codes, but not work.

i try

```
$ ./manage.py shell
>>> from new_way.core.models import Ordered, Customer, KitDetail
>>> ordered.kit_optional.kit_det.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'ordered' is not defined
>>> Ordered.kit_optional.kit_det.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'ReverseSingleRelatedObjectDescriptor' object has no attribute 'kit_det'
```

But not work.

And i dont say how to this.

Comment: Just to clarify: you have an `Ordered` object and you want to retrieve `accessory` and `price_accessory` fields from `Accessory` model, and `quantity_accessory` from `KitDetail` model? Note, that `KitDetail` has many to one relationship with `Kit` model, so, there may be more than one `KitDetail` object for each `Kit` object (the same for `Accessory` model).

Comment: @soon What do you suggest

Answer (score 0):

Every definition of `ForeignKey` adds a reverse relationship, which could be accessed using `related_name` (by default, it is `$model_name_lowercase$_set`). So, you could use the following code to get access to required objects:

```
ordered.kit_optional.kit_det.all() # Returns all KitDetail objects, related to oredered.kit_optional
```

You could iterate over it and retrieve related set of `Accessory` objects for each `KitDetail`:

```
{% for kit_detail in ordered.kit_optional.kit_det.all %}
    {{ kit_detail.quantity_accessory }}
    {% for accessory in kit_detail.accessory_kit.all %}
        {{ accessory.accessory }}
        {{ accessory.price_accessory }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I edit my question again, see my try code in `shell`.

Comment: Seems like, you haven't worked with Django before. You may try to read [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/). Hint: you could access first object of your model using `ModelName.objects.first()`

Comment: Sometimes I forget the basics ;)